# select from unpopulated table - IS NULL does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists, isnullorempty

SQL, Oracle --
I am trying to pull records from a table if Status = 'SO' or Status is Null.
I am only able to retrieve records if Status = 'SO' because if it is Null, it means the place I am pulling from is unpopulated - there is nothing there for it to look at.  It is almost like asking someone to tell them if they find a blank page in the book, but since it is blank, there really is no page to see, but the book still exists.  If the page had 'SO' on it, you could find it.

DGMR_DEGS_CODE can either be PN, AW, SO, or blank (nothing exists)

```
Select distinct sp.sprite_id as "ID", SP.SPRITE_LAST_NAME as "Last", SP.SPRITE_FIRST_NAME as "First", 
sh.TRAN_REQUEST_DATE as "Request Date",
NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE as "Null Dgr",
SV.RSTS_ENRL as "Enrolled?",
sf.stcr_term_code as "Term",
sysdate as "Current Date"


from Sprite SP

join TRAN SH 
on sp.sprite_pid = sh.tran_pid 

full outer join DGMR NL
on NL.DGMR_pid = sp.sprite_pid

join stcr sf
on sp.sprite_pid = sf.stcr_pid
JOIN stvrsts SV 
on SF.STCR_RSTS_CODE = SV.STVTS_CODE 

where 
Sp.sprite_change_ind is null

and sh.TRAN_REQUEST_DATE between sysdate-1 and sysdate
and (sf.stcr_term_code = '201401' or sf.stcr_term_code = '201402')
AND SV.RSTS_ENRL = 'Y'
AND (NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE is null or NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'SO' )
--and (length(NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE)=0 or NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'SO' )
--and NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE <> 'PN'
--and NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE <> 'AW'
--and NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE <> 'PN' and NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE <> 'AW'
```

If I do not include criteria for NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE, it selects 25 records: these records include SO, AW, PN, and NULL records!!
If I include criteria, it will not pull the NULL records.  Asking for SO or Null only selects SO records.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the `dgmr_degs_code` is actually NULL?  Rather than, say, one or more space characters?  The code you posted isn't using `IS NULL`-- the text of your question says that you're using `IS NULL` to return NULL values.  Are you certain that you're actually using `IS NULL` in your code?  If so, can you edit your SQL statement to show us exactly how you're using that?

Comment: I apologize.  The code above does not show "is null" because I had tried it, but it did not work.  I also tried ' '.  Is that even a real thing? or '%' ?
After Is Null and ' ' and '%' did not work, I tried (length(NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE)=0 or NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'SO' )

Comment: What does `dump(nl.dgmr_degs_code)` for one of the "empty" rows return?  That will show you exactly what is stored in the column.

Comment: I am not sure how to use that.  I put it at the end of my code, but i got an error.  When I do a desc on it, I get this (if this helps):  Name: DGMR_DEGS_CODE, Null?: NOT NULL, Type: VARCHAR2(8)

Comment: `dump` is a function-- you can put it in your `SELECT` clause to see what is actually stored in the column.  The column definition prevents NULL values so whatever is in that column, it isn't NULL.  It is some non-NULL value.  We just have to figure out what that value is.

Comment: @JustinCave I'm sorry to just reply.  I did not have access to test from home.  I'm not sure about the results, but I do not think they look promising.  There are only 3 results instead of 4 (AW, PN, SO, null/empty)

    DUMP(NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE)
    Typ=1 Len=2: 65,87
    Typ=1 Len=2: 80,78
    Typ=1 Len=2: 83,79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answered this, so I want to provide the answer for anyone else who may have a similar problem.
The field was "not null" so I had to do a TRIM in order to make it null.

I replaced the last line.

```
where 
Sp.sprite_change_ind is null
and sh.TRAN_REQUEST_DATE between sysdate-1 and sysdate
and (sf.stcr_term_code = '201401' or sf.stcr_term_code = '201402')
AND SV.RSTS_ENRL = 'Y'
and trim(NL.DGMR_DEGS_CODE) is null
```